# Text as hyperlink SQL

Tags: php, jquery, sql, mysqli

I created a table in my database that has 3 columns on it, the third column is a Download File column that has a text on it that can redirect to a file in my uploads folder. Any ideas on how to create the file download column?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var $table = $('#table');
         $table.bootstrapTable({
              url: 'list-user.php',
              search: true,
              pagination: true,
              buttonsClass: 'primary',
              showFooter: true,
              minimumCountColumns: 2,
              columns: [{
                  field: 'first',
                  title: 'Date',
                  sortable: true,
              },{
                  field: 'last',
                  title: 'Title',
                  sortable: true,

              },  {
                  field: 'file',
                  title: 'Download',
                  sortable: true,

              }],

         });
```

List-user file

```
 <?php 
    require 'db.php';

        $sqltran = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user ")or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $arrVal = array();

        $i=1;
        while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {

                        $name = array(
                                'num' => $i,
                                'first'=> $rowList['fname'],
                                'last'=> $rowList['lname']
                            );      


                            array_push($arrVal, $name); 
            $i++;           
        }
             echo  json_encode($arrVal);        


        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Use tags wisely to get more views.

Comment: @SankarRaj Please do not add deprecated tags to questions!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an array key/value for your `file` column. Hard to know where you store the filename without seeing your database structure, but replace `download_path_column_name` with the correct column name.

```
$name = array(
     'num' => $i,
     'first'=> $rowList['fname'],
     'last'=> $rowList['lname'],
     'file' => '<a href="' . $rowList['download_path_column_name'] . '">Download</a>'
);
```

Comment: The column name is file, but when i input your code, it doesnt show any datas anymore. I do have an upload folder containing pdf files. Any idea what to put in my column "file" field?

Comment: And you changed `$rowList['download_path_column_name']` to `$rowList['file']` ? @JayGarrick